# How to access tensor_content values in TensorProto in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Similar to [How to access values in protos in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124942/how-to-access-values-in-protos-in-tensorflow) but doesn't cater for this case.

I see a `bytes tensor_content` attribute in [TensorProto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto). I'm trying to get information about the nodes through:

`for node in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
    node.attr['value'].tensor.tensor_content # decode these bytes`

For information, the print of a node looks something like this:

```
name: "conv2d/convolution/Shape"
op: "Const"
device: "/device:GPU:0"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_INT32
      tensor_shape {
        dim {
          size: 4
        }
      }
      tensor_content: "\003\000\000\000\003\000\000\000\001\000\000\000 \000\000\000"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util

for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
    print tensor_util.MakeNdarray(n.attr['value'].tensor)
```

Comment: There is also `tf.make_ndarray`.

Answer (score 4):

Decode tensor_array bytes and then reshape with given shape:

```py
for node in tf.get_default_graph.as_graph_def().node:
    tensor_bytes = node.attr["value"].tensor.tensor_content
    tensor_dtype = node.attr["value"].tensor.dtype
    tensor_shape = [x.size for x in node.attr["value"].tensor.tensor_shape.dim]
    tensor_array = tf.decode_raw(tensor_bytes, tensor_dtype)
    tensor_array = tf.reshape(tensor_array, tensor_shape)
```